# Angular JS Error setting up dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ejs

I am trying to setup a dropdown field within a form but for some reason I get an error everytime I switch between the options in the dropdown.

```
 <select type="text" id="programeName" name="programme" placeholder="Select Programme" ng-show="<%= user.role === 'coach'%>" ng-model="session.programme"  required> 
    <option value="" disabled selected> Select Programme Name</option>
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
 </select>
```

I get the following error if switch from **one** to **two** or vice versa:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$$phase' of null
at Object.$$debounceViewValueCommit (angular.min.js:293)
at Object.$setViewValue (angular.min.js:293)
at Array.<anonymous> (angular.min.js:315)
at m.$digest (angular.min.js:145)
at m.$apply (angular.min.js:147)
at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (angular.min.js:320)
at bg (angular.min.js:38)
at HTMLSelectElement.d (angular.min.js:38)
```

**I have setup other dropdowns in the same form and they all work perfectly. What am I doing wrong in this one?**

Comment: controller code ??

Comment: are you using angular-ui?

Comment: Are you using any watch over the model

Comment: @DurgpalSingh  no I'm not using angular-ui.

Comment: @JijoCleetus No I'm not using any watch over the model.